# Add link to attachment for old posts

Tags: attachments

All images from posts have no link set! How I can add to all posts link to attachment ? There is a filter I can inject on functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`the_content` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to access the contents of the post before it is printed to the screen. The function that you use to filter it can either go two routes - using regex to parse the contents (not the "right" way but faster/dirtier) or an HTML parser. You should then be able to get to the `src` attribute and replace the `<img/>`.

```
function my_content_filter( $post_content ){
    // parse and modify the <imgs> in $post_content here
    return $post_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );
```

Keep in mind that if you go this route, the modified content's won't actually be stored in the database, so if something accesses `$post->post_content` without calling `apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content )` then your links won't be included. This will also put a relatively high load on your server to parse/modify the contents on every request, especially without a caching plugin in place. Programmatically accessing and updating the saved values might be a better choice if you want the updates to be ubiquitous.